# Move a LatLng 5 meters towards another LatLng

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, latitude-longitude

What algorithm/formula can I use to calculate a LatLng point 5 meters closer to another LatLng point? I'm trying to write a function with 2 LatLng parameters and have it return a LatLng that is 5 meters from the first LatLng and in the direction of the second LatLng.

Comment: Checkout this link: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html It might help. See the section (Destination point given distance and bearing from start point)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at Android Map Utils library, specifically the [SphericalUtil](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java) class.

1.) Call the method **computeHeading** to obtain your heading from first to second

2.) Call the method **computeOffset** to solve for the location 5 meters from your first point

Hope this helps