# Android: How to move a GPS Location object closer to another Location object

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm currently doing some research about a very small app I wanna try building.

The core concept will consist of moving randomly spawned GPS `Location` objects closer to the `Location` of the user as time passes by.

I have been looking through the `Location` API and as I understand all I need to do is updating the altitude and latitude of the spawned `Location` object to change its position. Now I'm curious what the best method is to: "Move a Location closer to another Location by 10 meter".

Is there already some existing API that achieves that goal like this hypothetical function:

`Location newLocation = Location.moveTo(Location locationFrom, Location locationTo, int distance);`

or do I have to write my custom algorithm?

What would be an efficient approach in this case? Any inputs are highly appreciated!

If the problem would exist in a Cartesian coordinate system I would just substract the user Location from the spawned Location to get the direction I need to move too and then add parts of the new vector to the spawned Location to get it closer.

How can this get solved with `Location`'s ?

**EDIT:** I sumbled upon this thread: [Move a LatLng 5 meters towards another LatLng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594445/move-a-latlng-5-meters-towards-another-latlng)

I guess using `SphericalUtil.java` is the way to do it.